# VSCode reverting is my changes when running or debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

Running VSCode in windows 10 -- local files

VSCode reverting is my changes when running or debugging - this is unwanted behavior.

this just started today - is driving me mad, MAD I TELL YOU!

Steps

1. make changes to code in .js file using VSCode editor
2. choose 'Start Debugging' or 'Run Without Debugging'
3. run window opens --> code is reverted in the editor window

I can get back my changes with ctrl-z  but then I'm stuck as I can't test any changes because they are reverted every time I try to debug or run.

*SOLUTION*

Leaving this here in case it helps someone -- SOMEHOW the editor got pointed to the 'out' directory instead of the project directory and I did not notice or even think of this happening - so *of course* it would change every time it was run - (because the run compiler replaces the code)

A big thanks to Nedam Kailash for engaging to keep my mind working on the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you render your .js file in your app main file??
or may be check for node, whether it is installed in your pc or not.

Comment: Hi thanks! -- i'm using no framework and typescript, not sure what you mean by 'render in app main file'  -- also yes, node is installed.   something changed today - i don't know what it was. going to try the whole 'uninstall everything' 'reinstall everything' next but is last resort

Comment: i mean to say, are you trying to debug your .js file code in vscode or the problem is not related to it.

Comment: yes am using F5 - to run the debugger in VSCode.  then the debug window opens -- then i see in the editor the code I just changed, revert.  So now I am debugging the old code, not what I just changed.

Comment: did you checked properly in lunch.jason file, for the program name to placed there correctly!

Comment: It runs fine - it debugs fine -- but SOMETHING is reverting my code changes and I do not want my code reverted on run  - i looked at launch.jason -   Here is the configuration in the launch.json (it probably will not render well)   {
   "name": "Run Extension",
   "type": "extensionHost",
   "request": "launch",
   "smartStep": true,
   "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
   "args": [
    "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
   ],
   "outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
   ],
   "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
  },

Comment: in my sense bro, may be the file that you are going to debug is not placed correctly, i recommend you to go through the documentation of vs code and there search for Debugging process, may be that will help you alot.